# Scala Type aliases for annotations

Tags: java, scala, annotations

In many points of my code, three annotations appears together:

```
@BeanProperty
@(SpaceProperty @beanGetter)(nullValue="0")
```

where `nullValue="0"` is a parameter to the annotation `SpaceProperty`.

Is it possible to define a single type alias for `@BeanProperty @(SpaceProperty @beangetter)` ?

The best I could do was:

```
type ScalaSpaceProperty = SpaceProperty @beanGetter

@BeanProperty
@(ScalaSpaceProperty)(nullValue = "0")
```

Is it possible to define a type alias for two annotations where the parameters are applied to the last one?

Comment: Are you using Scala with GigaSpaces? Wow!

Comment: http://edmondo1984.squarespace.com/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. You *can* write a macro to do this in Scala 2.10, I think (but the documentation isn't available at the moment, so I can't check).

Comment: You can't write a macro for this in 2.10.0. Maybe this feature will make it into 2.10.1, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 4):

The only example of type aliasing annotations I know is in [Scaladoc](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.annotation.target.package). Below follows the relevant part:

```
object ScalaJPA {
  type Id = javax.persistence.Id @beanGetter
}
import ScalaJPA.Id
class A {
  @Id @BeanProperty val x = 0
}
```

This is equivalent to writing `@(javax.persistence.Id @beanGetter) @BeanProperty val x = 0` in class A.

`type` declarations can only deal with types. In other words you can't provide instance information in type aliases.

One alternative is to try to extend the annotation. Below I created an hypothetical `SpaceProperty` for illustrative purposes:

```
scala> import scala.annotation._; import scala.annotation.target._; import scala.reflect._;
import scala.annotation._
import scala.annotation.target._
import scala.reflect._

scala> class SpaceProperty(nullValue:String="1",otherValue:Int=1) extends Annotation with StaticAnnotation

scala> class SomeClass(@BeanProperty @(SpaceProperty @beanGetter)(nullValue="0") val x:Int)
defined class SomeClass

scala> class NullValueSpaceProperty extends SpaceProperty(nullValue="0")
defined class NullValueSpaceProperty

scala> class SomeClassAgain(@BeanProperty @(NullValueSpaceProperty @beanGetter) val x:Int)
defined class SomeClassAgain
```

Using the type alias:

```
scala> type NVSP = NullValueSpaceProperty @beanGetter
defined type alias NVSP

scala> class SomeClassAgain2(@BeanProperty @NVSP val x:Int)defined class SomeClassAgain2
```

There one small problem with this solution. Annotations defined in Scala couldn't be retained during runtime. So if you need to use the annotation during runtime, you may need to do the extension in Java. I say *may* because I am not sure if this limitation already has been amended.

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
type MyAnnotation[+X] = @BeanProperty
                        @(SpaceProperty @beanGetter)(nullValue = 0) X

val myValue: MyAnnotation[MyType]
```