# Apply multiple annotation to a class and/or field using a single type alias in Scala

Tags: scala, serialization, annotations, deserialization, type-alias

After reading the usage of `scala.annotation.meta.field` https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/annotation/meta/index.html

Since I am using Xstream I am currently in need of setting the annotation `@XStreamAlias("alias")` for the field to change how they will be deserialised. For simplicity, I use a type alias:

```scala
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias

type xStreamAlias = XStreamAlias @field

@XStreamAlias("a")
case class A(@xStreamAlias("B") b: String)
```

I am using this in around 40 classes so I used a package object also for simplicity.

However I now would like to switch to Jackson and retain one single annotation that includes both Jackson and Xstream both for compatibility and simplicity. I would like to do something similar to this:

```scala
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty
import com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias

type alias = XStreamAlias JsonProperty @field

@alias("a")
case class A(@alias("B") b: String)
```

This way I hope to combine both Jackson and XStream into a single annotation, since they will be used in the same way.

My questions are:

1. Does this usage look correct and maintainable?
2. If you see the examples above, I am using such annotations only for fields and not for classes. Can the annotation be safely used even for classes?

I have never seen such usage of mixing 2 annotations with a type alias and to me it looks like as an improvement to maintainability and readability to centralise the behaviour of the chosen annotation.

I already saw this question: [Scala Type aliases for annotations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13310144/scala-type-aliases-for-annotations) but I am not sure if there is a new way to do so and the users that answered did not seem to be sure about their solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right hand side of `type xStreamAlias = XStreamAlias @field` is the type `XStreamAlias` annotated with `@field`. So `type alias = XStreamAlias JsonProperty @field` can't be correct syntax.

You can define a [macro annotation](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/annotations.html) that being expanded switches both `@XStreamAlias` and `@JsonProperty` on with proper (the same) parameters. You can define how to handle cases when `@alias` annotates a field and class separately.

```
import scala.annotation.{StaticAnnotation, compileTimeOnly}
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

@compileTimeOnly("Enable macro annotations")
class alias(name: String) extends StaticAnnotation {
  def macroTransform(annottees: Any*): Any = macro AliasMacro.impl
}

object AliasMacro {
  def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(annottees: c.Tree*): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._

    val name = c.prefix.tree match {
      case q"new alias(${nme: String})" => nme        
    }

    val XStreamAlias = tq"_root_.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias"
    val JsonProperty = tq"_root_.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty"
    val fieldAnnotation = tq"_root_.scala.annotation.meta.field"

    annottees match {
      // @alias annotates field
      case q"$_ val $valTName: $_ = $_" ::
        q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" ::
        objectOrNil =>

        // switch both @XStreamAlias and @JsonProperty on
        val paramss1 = paramss.map(_.map {
          case q"$paramMods val $paramTName: $paramTpt = $paramExpr" if paramTName == valTName =>
            val paramMods1 = paramMods.mapAnnotations(annotations =>
              q"new ($XStreamAlias @$fieldAnnotation)($name)" ::
                q"new ($JsonProperty @$fieldAnnotation)($name)" ::
                annotations
            )
            q"$paramMods1 val $paramTName: $paramTpt = $paramExpr"

          case param => param
        })

        q"""
          $mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss1) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }
          ..$objectOrNil
        """
          
      // @alias annotates class
      case q"$mods class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }" ::
        objectOrNil =>

        // switch only @XStreamAlias on
        val mods1 = mods.mapAnnotations(annotations =>
          q"new $XStreamAlias($name)" :: annotations
        )

        q"""
          $mods1 class $tpname[..$tparams] $ctorMods(...$paramss) extends { ..$earlydefns } with ..$parents { $self => ..$stats }
          ..$objectOrNil
        """
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
@alias("a")
case class A(b0: Int, @alias("B") b: String, b1: Boolean)

//scalac: {
//  @new _root_.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias("a") case class A extends scala.Product with scala.Serializable {
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val b0: Int = _;
//    @new _root_.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias @_root_.scala.annotation.meta.field("B") @new _root_.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty @_root_.scala.annotation.meta.field("B") <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val b: String = _;
//    <caseaccessor> <paramaccessor> val b1: Boolean = _;
//    def <init>(b0: Int, @new _root_.com.thoughtworks.xstream.annotations.XStreamAlias @_root_.scala.annotation.meta.field("B") @new _root_.com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty @_root_.scala.annotation.meta.field("B") b: String, b1: Boolean) = {
//      super.<init>();
//      ()
//    }
//  };
//  ()
//}
```

Comment: Nice usage, thanks a lot for the descriptive example also! This will probably require some rewriting if used with Scala 3 right?

Comment: @Jac Yeah, in Scala 3 currently macro annotations do not work. You can use [Scalameta](https://scalameta.org/)/[Scalafix](https://scalacenter.github.io/scalafix/) to expand annotations at pre-compile-time. https://scalacenter.github.io/scala-3-migration-guide/docs/macros/macro-libraries.html#macro-annotations-libraries Please notice that there is Simulacrum library for Scala 2 (compile time) and Simulacrum-Scalafix for Scala 3 (pre-compile-time).

Comment: Thanks! Really helpful info!